# Calling constructor of inherited class with only static methods

Tags: python, inheritance, constructor

I have two Python classes. One inherits from the other. Both contain only static methods. The inherited class has class variables that need to be initialized from an external config file. I was trying to come up with a way to get the inherited class's constructor called without creating an instance.

The code below is a lean example of what I'm doing. The code works. I'm not sure, however, if this is just bad practice. I have no reason NOT to instantiate the class before use. I just wanted to develop a solution that did not require an instance to do what I need it to since the class is just static methods. It IS required that the inherited class's constructor is called.

Also, can someone tell me what the happens to the NEW class instance I create in the method 'foo'?

```
import json

class Cloud(object):
    val = None  # ....................................... Class Variable

    def __init__(self):  # .............................. Class Constructor
        with open('config.dat', 'r') as f:
            dat = json.load(f)
        Cloud.val = dat['val']  # ....................... overwrite Class Variable
        print('Class Cloud -- constructor called.')

    @staticmethod
    def foo():  # ....................................... static method, does not require instance
        Cloud.__init__(Cloud.__new__(Cloud))  # ......... call the constructor on a NEW instance
        print('Class Cloud, class variable (val):={}'.format(Cloud.val))

class Sensor(Cloud):

    @staticmethod
    def bar():
        print('bar')

# run Static Method of Inherited Class Cloud
# call Class Cloud constructor
Sensor.foo()
```

EDIT:

The class Cloud is used to MQTT data to a cloud server. Many other classes inherit from this so data transmissions are easily handled. The class Sensor is used to collect data from various sensors. At no point are any instances of these classes required because the data just gets passed along. The reason I use classes is to group certain methods together, again not required. The only thing I need is to run the constructor of Cloud so that the class variables get updated. I could handle this inside the staticmethod, I just didn't.

Again, just looking for feedback. Good idea, bad idea...

Comment: since you never actually *use* `self` in your `__init__`, you can just `__init__` with a throwaway value, like `None`, `Cloud.__init__(None, ....)`. As for what happens to the instance you create in `foo`, it gets discarded immediately, since you don't save any references to it. This entire approach seems *radically* misguided. If you have a bunch of methods attached to a class, none of which use instance attributes, why in the world do you have a class at all?

Comment: IOW In Python, a class consisting entirely of static methods probably shouldn't be a class at all...

Comment: Maybe you could parse the contents of config.dat outside of the class, and give them to the class constructor as arguments? It seems like a bad pattern to have your class read stuff in from a file every time you make an instance of it.

Comment: @Alex. Agreed. I want to call Cloud constructor once only, regardless of how many times I use its methods.

Comment: Does this class have any non-static methods or variables?

Comment: No, it does not, but the config file can be updated at any time. The code runs once per hour, so if the config file changed, then class Cloud needs to use the latest updates for its class variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's effectively a static class variable, couldn't you just initialize it in the `class` definition?
I talking about something like this:

```
import json

class Cloud(object):
    with open('config.dat', 'r') as f:
        dat = json.load(f)
        val = dat['val']
        del dat  # Keep this variable from becoming a class attribute.

    def __init__(self):  # .............................. Class Constructor
#        with open('config.dat', 'r') as f:
#            dat = json.load(f)
#        Cloud.val = dat['val']  # ....................... overwrite Class Variable
        print('Class Cloud -- constructor called.')

    @staticmethod
    def foo():  # ....................................... static method, does not require instance
#        Cloud.__init__(Cloud.__new__(Cloud))  # ......... call the constructor on a NEW instance
        print('Class Cloud, class variable (val): {}'.format(Cloud.val))

class Sensor(Cloud):

    @staticmethod
    def bar():
        print('bar')

# run Static Method of Inherited Class Cloud
# call Class Cloud constructor
Sensor.foo()
```

This way you wouldn't need to construct a throw-away instance of `Cloud` to get the variable initialized. Besides, it seems inefficient to be reading the (whole) file in everytime an instance is created.

Comment: Excellent feedback! I actually did NOT know you could do this.

Comment: You can because `class` definitions in Python are executable and any variables that are created during that process become class attributes—just like any methods defined in them do. If you don't want a variable to become a class attribute, you'll need to delete it before the end (of the definition). One thing to bear in mind if you do this is that it occurs when the class is created (**not** when instances of it are, as was the case when it was in the `__init__()` method).

Comment: This only runs the class definition once even if I make multiple calls to Cloud's methods. I don't understand why? This IS the behavior I want, I just don't know what's going on under the hood. When is the class created?

Comment: twegner: It's designed that way. A class is created when its class definition is executed which usually only happens once during the execution of programs. I have no idea exactly when that happens in your situation. Could be when the file it's in is run explicitly as the main script or when it's `import`ed later as a result of some other script being run that does that.